# How are cookies managed in UIWebView and WKWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, wkwebview

I am migrating from UIWebView to WKWebView and facing problem in cookies management. As app need to support iOS 10 I am not adding cookies through WKHTTPCookieStore instead, I am following the below code:

```
- (void)loadURL:(NSString *)url
{
    NSMutableURLRequest * req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    NSArray* cookies = [storage cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    NSMutableString *cookieStr = [NSMutableString string];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
           if (cookieStr.length) {
               [cookieStr appendString:@"; "];
           }
           [cookieStr appendFormat:@"%@=%@", cookie.name, cookie.value];
    }
    NSLog(@"Cookie: %@",cookieStr);
    [req addValue:cookieStr forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];

    NSMutableString *cookieStrAfterDocLoad = [NSMutableString string];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
        [cookieStrAfterDocLoad appendFormat:@"document.cookie = '%@=%@';", cookie.name, cookie.value];
    }

    WKUserScript *userScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource: cookieStrAfterDocLoad
                                                      injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart
                                                   forMainFrameOnly:NO];

    [self.wkWebView.configuration.userContentController addUserScript:userScript];

    [self.wkWebView loadRequest:req];
}
```

I need to add the cookies after the document load to maintain the session for internal navigation.
This is not the correct way as the new cookies may be added or old may be modified at the time of page load. This needs to be done in many other controllers.

My question is how can I know if the cookies were added at every for loadRequst in UIWebview, or is there any other correct way to handle this situation in WKWebview as some webpage load might not need the cookies?
Is this the correct way to add cookies for every loadRequest?